# The apostrophes are not displayed when getting data from MySQL into bootstrap table

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, encoding

When I execute `SELECT` query in php in order to get data from MySQL DB into bootstrap table, the apostrophes are not displayed correctly in the table rows. In particular, I get `Gr�a` instead of `Grúa`.

This is how I get data from MySQL DB:

```
<?php
  include_once 'include/connect_db.php';

  $query = "SELECT * FROM myTable;";
  $result = ejecutar_query($query);

  $list = array();
  while ($b = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $list[] = $b;
  }
?>

<td><?php echo $row['name'];?></td>

<!--jQuery Datatable-->
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
              $('#myTable').dataTable({
              "sPaginationType":"full_numbers",
              "aaSorting":[[0, "asc"]],
              "bJQueryUI":true
              });

              hideLoading();

     });
</script>
```

Should I change the encoding in MySQL DB or what should I do to solve this issue?

Comment: does the select query work if you use it directly on the db?

Comment: @UmashankarDas: Yes, in DB it works fine.

Comment: Just use Markus Zeller's answer. It should work fine. ideally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode/decode the chars in that case. Changing the charset of the table/database may cause data loss.

```
<td><?php echo utf8_encode($row['name']);?></td>
```

if **utf8_encode()** does not work try **utf8_decode()** instead.

Comment: This would be the correct answer, But, it is important to confirm if , the data is stored in the db properly. Otherwise, none of the above would work.

Comment: To make it more properly you could even wrap it like that: `<?php echo html_entities(utf8_encode($row['name']));?>`. It just depends on the data.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use any encode/decode functions; that just compounds the problem.

See [*here*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored) for discussion of the causes and cures of "black diamond".